# ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value web service call

Tags: sql, oracle, web-services, soap

i am using the oracle apex and 10g database i use the following code to call the web service it gives me the folowing error

`ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value`

any one can help me thnx

the code i use is

```
{
    declare
    l_envelope CLOB;
    l_xml XMLTYPE;
    l_movie VARCHAR2(4000);
    BEGIN
    l_envelope := ' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.ignyte.com/whatsshowing"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
          <tns:GetTheatersAndMovies>
            <tns:zipCode>43221</tns:zipCode>
             <tns:radius>5</tns:radius>
           </tns:GetTheatersAndMovies>
               </soap:Body>
                 </soap:Envelope>';

       l_xml := apex_web_service.make_request(
        p_url => ' http://www.ignyte.com/webservices/ignyte.whatsshowing.webservice   \/moviefunctions.asmx',
     p_action => ' http://www.ignyte.com/whatsshowing/GetTheatersAndMovies',
     p_envelope => l_envelope );

   l_movie := apex_web_service.parse_xml(
     p_xml => l_xml,
     p_xpath => ' //GetTheatersAndMoviesResponse/GetTheatersAndMoviesResult/Theater/Movies/Movie/Name[1]',
     p_ns => ' xmlns="http://www.ignyte.com/whatsshowing"' );

         END;}
```